# 2D plane stress problem: a bent rod with one curved side squeezed

Tags: elasticity, solid-mechanics

Consider a bent rod (i.e., a sector of an annulus) of angle $\alpha$ and inner and outer radii $R_i$ and $R_o$. Now, we squeeze in azimuthally the lower face by an amount $\Delta$ (see the image below). [image]

The plane stress condition can be solved by using the biharmonic equation for the Airy potential. So my questions are related to the posing of the boundary conditions in this problem:

1. Can the problem be considered an axisymmetric problem? Or a quasi-axisymmetric one? Why/why not?
2. Are the boundary conditions on the loaded face best described in terms of stresses or displacements? The natural way is through displacements. Putting the origin at the centroid, we have: 
   $$
   u_{\theta} = \pm \Delta \;@ \; r=R_i, \theta=\pm \alpha/2 \\
   u_{\theta} = 0 \;@ \; r=R_o
   $$ so this can be modelled via an odd function (a linear one would be the simplest).
3. But the squeezing in also looks like a shear strain of magnitude $\Delta/(R_o-R_i)$ : 
   $$ 
   \epsilon_{r\theta} = \pm \Delta/(R_o-R_i) \;@ \; r=R_i \\
   \epsilon_{r\theta} = 0 \;@ \; r=R_o. $$ Is this statement correct? If so, could I again interpolate linearly between the oppositely signed values at $\theta=\pm \alpha/2$?
4. What would be the boundary conditions on the side faces? Will weak boundary conditions suffice?
5. Lastly, it would seem to me that the qualitative effect of such a loading would be a further bending of the bent rod. Can I thus approximate the solution by considering the pure bending problem where the only loading is a constant moment $M$ applied on the side faces? This would truly make it an axisymmetric problem.

I am new to 2D elasticity, and I really appreciate all the help I can get.